Google App Engine instances high memory usage
We are using Google App Engine automatic scaling for quite some time now and I always wondered about the memory usage that it has. We have a Flask app that is 56 MB big on a local machine (before deploying). On a local machine in virtual environment the app is using around 40 MB of memory.
After deploying the app to Google Cloud (even though we set the gcloudignore file so that venv and local database are not deployed), the size of the container in Artifact Registry is 534 MB. This is one thing that I don't understand, why the container is so much bigger than the actual app. I'm suspecting because a container has other stuff inside it like OS and supporting plugins to run the app?
Then the next interesting thing is that when you look at the memory usage, it's constantly using at least 1.56 GB of memory per 1 instance (one instance has 1.6GB of memory).
Constant memory usage of 1.56 GB
This seems way too much memory usage for a simple Flask app. Here is the app.yaml, we have to use the F4_1G instance class, otherwise the app does not have enough memory (500 Internal Server error and in the logs it states that the system ran out of memory).
app.yaml file
I'm kind of new to Google Cloud so any help would be appreciated.
I expected the memory usage and container image would be a lot smaller (the billing is expensive for instance class F4_1G). If usage would be less, then we could lower the instance class and have cheaper billing.

I have a reasonably complex Flask app that uses about 800MB per instance.  I suspect that your chart shows total memory usage of two instances and not memory of 1 instance.
I think that running a Flask app cannot be done with much less than 800MB memory.  It doesn't make sense, but that is just how it works on Google cloud.
Also, FYI, it looks like you are using GAE standard but your app.yaml has things that only work for GAE flexible.

Thanks for your answer. I doubt it's showing memory usage for 2 instances however, because if I look for the same time range, you can see 1.60 GB memory usage and 1 instance running at that time. Also thanks for mentioning the app.yaml file, I didn't even know that you can have flexible and standard GAE. Can I ask which one do you use for your Flask app just for reference?

@JanVerderber: This doc compares standard and flexible. Note that if you don't specify env attribute in your app.yaml file, Google assumes you're using standard but as @minou pointed out you've included a bunch of attributes that are for flex. I wonder if that has led to inconsistencies which affect your env

@NoCommandLine Thanks for some clarifications. However even after fixing the app.yaml file, the app is still using 1.6GB of memory with F4_1G instance class, while only one instance is running. I tried lowering the instance class to F4 but it said that GAE ran out of memory...

@ThyR4n I found out you have to manually delete them from artifact registry, even though I set up TTL so they should be deleted automatically... I guess it's bugged on the Google side. But that still doesn't fix my problem, it just saves us a bit of money each month
